# No recovery from hsqldb log-file

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, hsqldb

I have a small Web-Application based on Java/JSP/Hsqldb/Tomcat/Maven and the following problem with Hsqldb:

Currently I've no call of `shutdown` or `checkpoint` within the application, so the committed sql statements are inserted only into the **.log** file of *Hsqldb*.

When I want to easily test an update of the application, I do it by replacing the war-file with the newer one within the **webapps** folder of tomcat. After logging into my web application, the data presented out of the database is incomplete/old, because the sql statements within the **.log** file are ignored.
The documentation of Hsqldb tells that if a crash occurs, the replay of the contents of the **.log** file is done automatically but in my situation this isn't the case.

What is the best way for me to handle this *kind of crash*?

- calling `checkpoint` after every `commit` or at least periodically?
- using the connection parameter `hsqldb.full_log_replay=true`?
- any other idea?

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must set the WRITE DELAY to a 0 or a low value. This ensures data changes are actually logged. Check the .script file for your current setting.

Calling CHECKPOINT periodically is fine, but not after each commit.

To ensure playback use `hsqldb.full_log_replay=true`. Check the .log file if there is an error when opening the database. The error arises if some lines are not fully written out.

Comment: The write delay wasn't my point since I am currently the only user of the application and the default delay is 500ms. The other points are helping.